# Seeding WebApplicationFactory For Integration Tests Doesn't Save and Gives a 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, .net-core, integration-testing

So I'm trying to create a integration test with preseeded data in my dbcontext, but for some reason it's not saving my entry to the database and gives me a 404 not found after I get my response back. Happy to expand or clarify anything if needed.

Cheers

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetPet_ReturnsResourceWithAccurateFields()
{
    var fakePet = new FakePet { }.Generate();
    fakePet.PetId = 1;

    var appFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<StartupAutomatedTesting>()
        .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.Remove(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(MyDbContext),
                        typeof(MyDbContext)));
                    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb");
                    });

                    var serviceProvider = services
                        .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                        .BuildServiceProvider();

                    using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                    {
                        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
                        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                        context.Pets.AddRange(fakePet);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                });
        });

    var testingClient = appFactory.CreateClient();


    var result = await testingClient.GetAsync($"/v1/Pets/{fakePet.PetId}");
    var responseContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PetDto>(responseContent);

    // Assert
    response.Name.Should().Be(fakePet.Name);
    response.Age.Should().Be(fakePet.Age);
}
```

Comment: welcome - please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I tried to keep it minimal yet complete by providing the entirety of the test code,but what else would you need me to add? This isn't really fully reproducible without sharing the entire project.

Comment: logs and the controller would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because of the (intermediate) service provider you create which gets its own singleton instance of the in memory database.

Move the seeding portion after creating the appFactory and resolve the dbcontext from the service provider from the `appFactory`:

```
var appFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<StartupAutomatedTesting>()
   .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
   {
       ... etc ...
   });

using (var scope = appFactory.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    context.Pets.AddRange(fakePet);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

var testingClient = appFactory.CreateClient();

... etc ...
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. This makes sense, but I'm not seeing a Services definition to use in a WebApplicationFactory or a way to drill into it other than inside of the webhostbuilder like I had in the OP. Any suggestions? Will keep digging myself as well.

Comment: I'm afraid it's only available for .NET Core 3.x https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1.services?view=aspnetcore-3.0 But it should just be a shortcut to `appFactory.Server.Host.Services`